# How does GraphQL Mutation associate itself with Type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, prisma

When I set up my schema as following:

```
type Mutation {
    createUser(data: CreateUserInput!): User!
}

type User {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    password: String!
    email: String!
    posts: [Post!]!
    comments: [Comment!]!
}
```

and my resolver:

```
const Mutation = {
    async createUser(parent, args, { prisma }, info) {
        if(args.data.password.length < 8) {
            throw new Error("Pasword must be 8 characters or longer")
        }
        return prisma.mutation.createUser({ 
            data: {
                ...args.data,
                password
            } 
        })
    }
}
```

how does GraphQL know that `createUser` is associated with my `User` model?  I could set it up so that `createUser` returns token instead of User (after generating a token) or I could rename `createUser` to `createPerson`. I have never defined the association between `createUser` and `User`.  I'm unsure how my data input through `createUser` gets directed to be saved in the `user` table, instead of another table.

Comment: Are you asking about the `User` type in your schema and `prisma.mutation.createUser`?

Comment: Yes that's correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no association between the two.

Your resolver could just as easily return a plain object with some dummy data:

```
async createUser(parent, args, { prisma }, info) {
  ...
  return { 
    id: 1,
    name: 'Kevvv',
    password: 'password',
    email: 'kevvv@stackoverflow.com',
  }
}
```

or use some other means of fetching the user:

```
async createUser(parent, args, { prisma }, info) {
  ...
  return fetchUserFromAPI()
  // or some other data source like a DB
}
```

`prisma.mutation.createUser` returns a Promise that resolves to an object which represents the created user. This object happens to have properties that match the `User` type you specified in your schema, but otherwise there's nothing "special" about it.

Comment: How does the mutation create a table specifically named User within my Postgres or MongoDB then?

Comment: Playground interface also automatically shows all the User properties like name, email, etc when executing createUser

Comment: Your mutation creates a row in your DB because you call `prisma.mutation.createUser` inside its resolver. The Prisma client is auto-generated from the datamodel definitions you provide for your Prisma server. You define a `User` datamodel and when the client is generated, it automatically creates the appropriate Prisma client methods.

Comment: Playground is showing the `User` type from your schema, not from Prisma. The two are only related in so far as your schema relates them. You could, for example, call your schema type `User` but call the datamodel `Person`. Then your table would be called Person and the client call would be `prisma.mutations.createPerson`, but nothing else would change.

Comment: I think I'm still confused. In MongoDB, I specifically instantiate something like new User({ user: req.userId }) in my resolver so that the mutation is associated with the User model. In my Prisma example above, there is no mention of any Types in the resolver.  If I had MemberA and MemberB in my datamodel with the same properties like name and email (which is a contrived example), how will my resolver createMember know which one to associate with?

Comment: If you have `MemberA` and `MemberB` in your datamodel, your prisma client will end up with two "create" calls -- `prisma.mutations.createMemberA` and `prisma.mutations.createMemberB` -- it's up to you to call the appropriate one inside the resolver

Comment: Ok, I think I'm beginning to understand. My mistake was in thinking that prisma.graphql is being auto-generated from schema.graphql with queries and mutations that I've defined myself.  But, prisma.graphql is actually derived from datamodel.prisma only.  And I design my resolver around the queries and mutations prisma.graphql gives me.  Is this correct?